# dynamic jasper report multi row header

Tags: jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

using "Dynamic Jasper", how do you create table header(addColumn) that has multiple rows?

for example

```
HEADING1 | HEADING2 | HEADING3
HEADING4 | HEADING5 | HEADING6
HEADING7 | HEADING8 | HEADING9
=====================================================
VALUEFORHEADING1, VALUEFORHEADING2, VALUEFORHEADING3
VALUEFORHEADING4, VALUEFORHEADING5, VALUEFORHEADING6
VALUEFORHEADING7, VALUEFORHEADING8, VALUEFORHEADING9
-----------------------------------------------------
VALUEFORHEADING1, VALUEFORHEADING2, VALUEFORHEADING3
VALUEFORHEADING4, VALUEFORHEADING5, VALUEFORHEADING6
VALUEFORHEADING7, VALUEFORHEADING8, VALUEFORHEADING9
------------------------------------------------------
```

thanks

UPDATE

Or any other libs that can generate dynamic jasper report like this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not doable in DJ, but it's possible using [DynamicReports](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net),
here is an [example](http://dynamicreports.sourceforge.net/examples/manycolumnsreport.html)

Comment: I can't see where it says in your example that there are only 3 columns in one row as requested!? `col` and `type` seem also undefined